# Grabing text using Selenium/XPath/Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to grep the total number of deaths from the [Johns Hopkins Covid dashboard](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html). I want to do this using Selenium, Python and Selenium’s chrome driver. The number of deaths can be found under the path `//*[@id="ember1915"]/svg/g[2]/svg/text`.

[image]

This is my script:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

with Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get('https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20) # Waits for 20 s for the entire page to loads.
    

    diplayElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1915"]/svg/g[2]/svg/text')
```

It fails with the error “no such element:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ember1915"]/svg/g[2]/svg/text"}”.
```

This also happens for other sites I’m trying to scrape.

How can I fix this? What’s the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

The element with the total number of deaths i.e. **905,181** from the [Johns Hopkins Covid dashboard](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html) is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Coronavirus COVID-19 Global Cases by Johns Hopkins CSSE']")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='text' and text()='Global Deaths']//following::div[1]/*[name()='svg' and @class='responsive-text-group']//*[name()='g' and @class='responsive-text-label']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='text']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

    ```
    driver.get('https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Coronavirus COVID-19 Global Cases by Johns Hopkins CSSE']")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='text' and text()='Global Deaths']//following::div[1]/*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='text']"))).text)
    ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  905,181
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: How are you sure that it will return text or inner html without selecting an iframe ? I would like to know even without selecting the shadow element how it will do this.

Comment: @Dev Nice catch, just slipped out while copying the code, corrected it now.